# How to cancel a tcpclient stream on Delphi and Indy 10.6

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy

I'm setting up a TCP client/server app, where I send a header record to the server (and possibly a file stream), and it will respond with a response record (and possibly a file stream).

But some times, I get stream errors (both sides), and I can't seem to clear them with `IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear()`.

Here's some example code:

CLIENT SIDE

```
var
  FS: TFileStream;

FClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
try
  FClient.IOHandler.Write(FS, FS.Size, True); //send the file w/size
finally
  FreeAndNil(FS);
end;
```

SERVER SIDE

```
var
  FS: TFileStream;

//in ServerExecute
FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate Or fmOpenWrite); //create the file
IdContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
try
  if IdContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then //if no data yet
    if not IdContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(30000) then
    begin //read timeout
      SErr := 'read time out, stream not received!';
      Exit;
    end;
  IdContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(FS, -1, False); //read stream with size specified at start of stream
  if FS.Size <> (expected file size sent in header packet) then
  begin
    SErr := 'not all stream bytes received!';
    Exit;
  end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(FS); //close the file
end;
```

Regardless of whether it is the server or client side receiving, when I do `IdContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(FS, -1, False)` it will freeze on the stream intermittently (probably because the transfer count is less than the expected bytes).  Once I detect a timeout condition, I will clear the input buffer, but from then on it's like the transfers are out of sync; i.e. I send a command packet, then the file packet, but I get an error like it received the file packet first, and it keeps doing that for the following failure retries.

Comment: If you get a read timeout in the middle of an actual read operation, you can't just clear the `InputBuffer` and move on.  You don't know what you are actually clearing, where in the read the timeout actually occurred, or whether there are still bytes being transmitted and haven't been received yet. Usually, the only sane thing you can do is just close the connection. Unless your packets have a unique delimiter that you can use with `TIdIOHandler.WaitFor()` so you can get back in sync.

Comment: Also, if you are sending a preceding record header that contains the stream size, there is no need to duplicate the stream size when sending the actual stream, that is just wasted bandwidth. Set `AWriteByteCount=False` in `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)`, and pass the stream size from the record header as the `AByteCount` to `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()`